# Creating a "valid" user in Microsoft AD using Python

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

Has anyone every successfully managed to create a valid and "working" user in Active Directory using Python ?

I've tried my best by using the https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/ module but could not for the life of me get it to create the user...

The closest I ever got was using this piece of code:

```
conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://' + ldap_hostname)
conn.protocol_version = 3 
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
conn.simple_bind_s(ldap_admin_dn, ldap_admin_pw)

attrs = {}
attrs['objectClass'] = ['top'.encode('utf-8'), 'person'.encode('utf-8'), 'organizationalPerson'.encode('utf-8'), 'user'.encode('utf-8')]
attrs['cn'] = "Test User".encode("utf-8")
attrs['userPrincipalName'] = "testuser@domain.com".encode("utf-8")
attrs['displayName'] = "Test User".encode("utf-8")
attrs['givenName'] = "Test".encode("utf-8")
attrs['sn'] = "User".encode("utf-8")
attrs['sAMAccountName'] = "testuser".encode("utf-8")
attrs['mail'] = "testuser@domain.com".encode("utf-8")
attrs['primaryGroupID'] = "513".encode("utf-8")

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

# Set up user dn
user_cn = "Test User"
user_dn = "CN={},{}".format(user_cn, ldap_users_ou_dn)

# Create user
conn.add_s(user_dn, ldif)

# Set initial password
password_value = "LaLaLaLaLa123123123!".encode('utf-16-le')

add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
conn.modify_s(user_dn, add_pass)

# Set user account control
mod_acct = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'userAccountControl', '66048')]
conn.modify_s(user_dn, mod_acct)
```

But unfortunately, it fails on `conn.add_s` with this error message:

```
"errorMessage": "{'msgtype': 105, 'msgid': 2, 'result': 53, 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform', 'ctrls': \[\], 'info': '00000529: SvcErr: DSID-031A124C, problem 5003 (WILL\_NOT\_PERFORM), data 0\\n'}", "errorType": "UNWILLING\_TO\_PERFORM",
```

Am I pushing wrong arguments? Am I encoding them badly? What am I doing wrong ? Any help or "piece of code" which you guys actually used to make it work would be awesome ...

Again, this is specifically intended to connect to MICROSOFT AD, and not OpenLDAP.

Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"Unwilling to perform" always means that you're doing something wrong - usually assigning a value that is not allowed.

In your case, I suspect it is this line:

```
attrs['primaryGroupID'] = "513".encode("utf-8")
```

The [`primaryGroupID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygroupid) attribute is an integer, not a string. So that should likely look like this:

```
attrs['primaryGroupID'] = 513
```

And I'm not sure you need to use `.encode("utf-8")` for all of the string values. If it still doesn't work after correcting the `primaryGroupID` value, then try removing the encoding.

Comment: Hi @gabriel-luci,

I've tried both ideas, unfortunately without success.

If I push "primaryGroupID" value of 513 as INT I get this ->

```
"errorMessage": "'int' object is not iterable",
```

when running ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs).

And if I remove the encoding, I get this ->

```
"errorMessage": "('Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): expected a byte string in the list', 'top')",
```

for  conn.add_s(user_dn, ldif)

Comment: @MariusMitrofan Does the value of `user_dn` look right after you construct it?

Comment: Even if the directory schema defines values as integers, they are still transferred on the wire as decimal ASCII strings (and OP is using python-ldap which doesn't do any fancy schema-based transforms, directly exposing the raw bytestrings), so I believe that part is already correct – the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @user1686 Fair enough. I'm a C# developer mostly, not Python. In the C# libraries, integer values like `primaryGroupID` are set and exposed as integers, so that's why it stood out to me.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `unicodePwd` must *include the quotes* as part of the string (presumably so that the server could confirm that the correct UTF-16 encoding is being used), [see protocol specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). The server will discard the quotes before hashing the password.

```py
attrs["unicodePwd"] = "\"Hello!\"".encode("utf-16le")
```

You should just set `unicodePwd` and especially `userAccountControl` immediately when creating the entry – there is no need to do so through separate modify operation.

On the other hand, you do not need to set `primaryGroupID` if it's the default value; just leave it out.

---

I would also recommend using constants, or even `enum`, for things like the `userAccountControl` attribute instead of hardcoding "magic numbers":

```py
class UacFlags(enum.IntEnum):
    NORMAL_ACCOUNT       = 0x200
    DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD = 0x10000
    #NormalAccount        = 0x200
    #DontExpirePassword   = 0x10000

flags = int(UacFlags.NORMAL_ACCOUNT | UacFlags.DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD)

attrs["userAccountControl"] = str(flags).encode()
```

Comment: Good catch on the password. I didn't notice that. Although the error is coming from before the password is being set, so it must be something else. I do wonder if it's the `objectClass`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who got here, here's what I noticed from my tests:

- You CANNOT create a password while creating the user
- When creating a password, your LDAP connections must be encrypted (SSL/TLS), otherwise the server will "reject it" if you're using any LDAP Python library out there
- Because you CANNOT create a password when creating the user, the user must first be created as DISABLED
- Only after you find "a way" to set up password, you can set the user as ENABLED
- All strings must be encoded as UTF-8

As such, considering the fact that my environment was in AWS and I was using AWS Microsoft AD Standard, here's my working example:

```
ldap_admin_pw = "MyAdminPassword123!"
ldap_hostname = "ldap.server.com"
ldap_admin_dn = "CN=Admin,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
ldap_users_ou_dn = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"

conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://' + ldap_hostname)
conn.protocol_version = 3
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX, 0)
conn.simple_bind_s(ldap_admin_dn, ldap_admin_pw)
print('Successfully authenticated against LDAP server.')

print('Attempting to create user...')

attrs = {
    'objectClass': [
        'top'.encode('utf-8'),
        'person'.encode('utf-8'),
        'organizationalPerson'.encode('utf-8'),
        'user'.encode('utf-8')
    ], 
    'cn': "Random Guy".encode("utf-8"),
    'userPrincipalName': "randomguy@domain.com".encode("utf-8"),
    'displayName': "Random Guy".encode("utf-8"),
    'givenName': "Random".encode("utf-8"),
    'sn': "Guy".encode("utf-8"),
    'sAMAccountName': "randomguy".encode("utf-8"),
    'mail': "random.guy@domain.com".encode("utf-8"), 
    'userAccountControl': "514".encode("utf-8")
}

# Set up user dn
user_cn = "Random Guy"
user_dn = "CN={},{}".format(user_cn, ldap_users_ou_dn)

# Create user
attrs_ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)
conn.add_s(user_dn, attrs_ldif)
print('Successfully created user with DN as {}'.format(user_dn))

# Wait a few seconds for AD to sync up
# I've noticed that if you attempt to create
# The password immediately after creating the user
# You might get a "user does not exist"
# Probably because it takes a few seconds
# For the Domain Controllers to sync up
# The new user you created

print('Waiting for user to be synchronized across domain controllers...')
time.sleep(10)

# Set new password
# I am in an AWS environment
# Therefore I am using the boto3 library
# To connect to AWS Directory Service
# And set up the password for the existing user

print('Attempting to set up password for user...')
client = boto3.client('ds', region_name=base_directory_region)
client.reset_user_password(
    DirectoryId=base_directory_id,
    UserName="randomguy",
    NewPassword="SomeLongThingHere123!"
)
print('Successfully set up password for user.')

# Set user account control
print('Activating user...')
mod_acct = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'userAccountControl', '66048'.encode('utf-8'))]
conn.modify_s(user_dn, mod_acct)
print('Successfully activated user.')
```